# Getting java.net.unknown host exception when trying to selenium scripts remotely in grid from jenkins running in linux

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

Can anyone help me on below problem

Jenkins running in Linux server trying to run selenium scripts in selenium grid hosted in Windows
Stage in Jenkinsfile:

```
Stage("Functionaltest")
Checkout:scm
steps.sh(script: Gradle Functionaltest)
```

Thanks,
Yaswanth

Comment: Can you include the exact error message and stack trace? Can you post the plain text output of the build in Jenkins? We need more information to solve your problem.

Comment: I got it solved by replacing the hostname with ip address of the machine. Thanks eg:http://hostname:4444/wd/hub to http://ipaddress:4444/wd/hub

Comment: Update the question with the error stack trace

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.

For those who have installed selenium grid in the same machine running the tests, simply use:

```
    http://localhost:4444
```